# mvn install stuck after some percentage while downloading jansi.jar file

Tags: maven, installation, jar, mvn-repo, jansi

I am running a Maven project for which I have a private remote repository using JFrog Artifactory that I have included in my Maven `settings.xml` file. All the dependencies are getting downloaded successfully but for one particular JAR i.e. `jansi-1.17.1.jar` the download process stops in between (say at 177 kB) and after that nothing happens.

I am not sure what's going wrong for this particular JAR file. I have tried downloading this JAR via browser and it's getting downloaded from there. Below is the Maven output:

```
Downloading from organization: http://artifact.organisation.intra:8081/artifactory/orgname/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.17.1/jansi-1.17.1.jar
Progress (1): 177/284 kB
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete the artifact's directory in your local and your Artifactory repo so that it is newly downloaded from the external remote repo?

Comment: @GeroldBroser deleting them several times didn't work for me.

Comment: Which external repo(s) do you use? Is there any message before or after the lines of of the mvn output you mention regarding repo connection or the like?